# Integration with trigonometry

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, indefinite-integrals

We have to find this integration. I am little weak in integration .

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin x\sqrt{\sin(2x+\alpha)}}$$I tried the substitution of $2x + a = t$ , and tried to expand the sine term but no result , I got from this .

Comment: could please use $tex$ instead of posting pictures all the time

Comment: @tired but please it is very convinient to me

Comment: but maybe not for the users you are asking for help?

Comment: @tired why is the image not so clear ??

Comment: Your blind readers are unable to read your picture.  If it were $\TeX$, their technology could read it to them.  Your picture cannot be indexed and searched so future identical questions cannot find your picture.

Comment: @EricTowers who are blind reader , are they not human . And sorry if you think I am rude.

Comment: You asked "why is the image not so clear ??".  Using an image instead of $\TeX$ has at least two defects, which I have identified.  This is a Q&A site;  it should not be surprising that when you ask a question you get an answer.

Comment: @EricTowers but these are minor defects . I think there should be no problem from this .

Comment: additionaly you can copy content from the question to a potential answer which might reduce the amount of work...and it looks nicer

Comment: @tired but in my question there is not too much work shown by me , that you can copy . And through image also it is looking good .

Comment: i am not in the mood to discuss the basic behaviour expected at this site with you...accept it or live with the consequences (downvotes, less answers, critical comments...)

Comment: @tired fine , I accept it . Now please help me in this .

Comment: Are you sure that this is the integral you have to compute? According to WolframAlpha the solution is quite nasty.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B%5Csin+x%5Csqrt%7B%5Csin(2x%2B%5Calpha)%7D%7D

Comment: Call the integral in question $I(\alpha)$ and perform a substitution $z=e^{2ix}$ we get

$$
I(\alpha)=\sqrt{2i}\beta\int dz\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{z}^{-1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta^2z-z^{-1}}}
$$

where we have set $\beta^2=e^{2i\alpha}$. this equals

$$
I(\alpha)=\sqrt{2i\beta}\int dz\frac{1}{z-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta^2z^2-1}}
$$

can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{\alpha}}} \log{\left( \frac{\sin{(x+\alpha)}-\sqrt{\sin{\alpha}\sin{(2x + \alpha)}}}{\sin{x}} \right)} + \mathcal{C} $$

Steps:

1. Shift the $\alpha$ out of the surd with the substitution $x = u-\frac{\alpha}{2}$.
2. Expand the sine on the outside using compound angles, and expand the sine under the surd using double angles.
3. Divide throughout by $\cos^2{u}$ and then use the substitution $t = \tan{u}$.
4. Use the substitution $v = \sqrt{t}$

The integral is thus trivial and the back-substitution and trigonometric simplification is left as an exercise to the interested reader.

Comment: much better (+1)